# Изменить цвет фона Assembler

Tags: ассемблер

Необходимо изменить цвет фона на жёлтый, как это сделать?

```
.486
    model small 
    Code SEGMENT use16 
    ASSUME cs:Code, ds:Code 
    org 100h 
    start: 
    push cs 
    pop ds 
    mov ax, 0b800h 
    mov es, ax 
    xor ax, ax 
    mov di, ax 
    mov cx, 2000 
    rep stosw 
    mov di, 1670    
    mov ah, 0Ch ;Как изменить фон на жёлтый?
    lea si, mess 
    mov cx, 12 
    next0: 
    lodsb 
    stosw 
    loop next0 
    next1: 
    in al, 60h
    cmp al, 1 
    jne next1 
    int 13h 
    mess db "Hello world!", 0
    Code ENDS 
    end start
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Перед тем как задавать атрибуты текста и фона прямой записью в видеобуфер `0xB800`, нужно установить соответствующий видеорежим - обычно это 80х25/16, чем занимается `INT-10h: AH=0, AL=3` (или просто АХ=3). Этого требует счётчик в регистре `CX` при заполнении в/буфера.
2. Сам буфер в текстовом режиме(3) организован в виде "2 байта на каждый из 80*25=2000 символов" - в старшем байте лежит атрибут, а в младшем непосредственно код символа. При этом атрибут делится на две тетрады - в старшей цвет фона (для жёлтого `=0хЕ`), а в мл.тетраде цвет текста. То-есть, чтобы определить чёрный символ на жёлтом фоне, нужно установить `0xE020`, где 20h это второй байт со-значением "пробел". Вот пример на FASM'e:

```
org  0x100
jmp  start

mess   db    13,10,' Hello World! $'

start:
;// Ставим видео-моду 80х25/16
       mov   ax,3
       int   0x10

;// Забиваем видео-буфер нужными атрибутами
       push  0xb800
       pop   es
       xor   di,di      ;// ES:DI = указатель на в/буфер (приёмник для stosw)
       mov   cx,80*25   ;// кол-во символов в буфере
       mov   ax,0xE020  ;// атрибут = цвет фона(Е), цвет текста(0), символ(20=пробел)
       rep   stosw      ;// записать АХ в ES:DI, по длине СХ

;// Выводим текст на консоль
       mov   ah,9
       mov   dx,mess
       int   0x21

;// Ждём любую клавишу, и на выход
       xor   ax,ax
       int   0x16
       int   0x20
```

Comment: mov ah, 0Ch изменил на mov ah, E2h. Появляется ошибка: "Неопределённый символ: E2h"(но при 2Eh - всё нормально). 
Пишу  в GUI Turbo Assembler.

Comment: перечитайте внимательно вторую часть ответа

Comment: Запись     mov ah, 0xE020 его тоже не устраивает: **Error** 123.ASM(17) Illegal number

Answer (score 2):

У меня тасма нет, но должно быть примерно так:

```
.486
model   small
Code    SEGMENT use16
ASSUME  cs:Code, ds:Code
org 100h

start:
    push  cs
    pop   ds

    mov   ax,3
    int   10h

    mov   ax,0b800h
    mov   es,ax
    mov   di,1670   ;// ES:DI = видео/буфер

    mov   ah,0E0h   ;//<--- фон жёлтый
    lea   si,mess
    mov   cx,12
next0:
    lodsb 
    stosw 
    loop  next0

next1:
    in    al,60h
    cmp   al,1
    jne   next1
    int   20h

mess db "Hello world!", 0

Code ENDS
end start
```

Comment: По итогу получается оранжевый фон, хотя по заданию требуют именно жёлтый.

Comment: Ну так покрути атрибут в разные стороны, или тоже за вас нужно сделать? Хотя у меня выводит именно жёлтый фон(Е) + чёрный текст(0).

Comment: В том и дело, как я не пытался - всё равно оранжевый. Зато если атрибут записать как: 0EEh, то буквы станут жёлтыми, но фон всё равно будет как не крути оранжевым