# нужен код который меняет цвет фона после нажатие нужной клавиши assembler (цвет синий)

Tags: ассемблер

```
.model small
.data
combined db 27,'[0;1;43m','use WASD to move [ ]$',27,'[0m$'
draw_0 db 27,'[0m  ',27,'[0;1;36;46m________',27,'[0m  $'
draw_1 db 27,'[0m ',27,'[0;1;36;46m|      _ |',27,'[0m$'
draw_2 db 27,'[0m ',27,'[0;1;36;46m|_____|.||',27,'[0m$'
draw_3 db 27,'[0m ',27,'[0;1;31;45m ()    () ',27,'[0m $'
posX db 5
posY db 5
.code

CLEAR:
    MOV     AH, 0
    MOV     AL, 2
    INT     10h


    mov     AH, 2
    mov     BH, 0
    mov     DH, 1
    mov     DL, 1
    int     10H
    mov     ah,9h
    lea     dx,combined 
    int     21h
RET

SETPOS:
    mov     AH, 2
    mov     BH, 0
    mov     DH, posY
    mov     DL, posX
    int     10h
RET

DRAW:
    call        SETPOS
    mov     ah,9h
    lea     dx,draw_0
    int     21h

    add     posY,1; 
    call        SETPOS
    mov     ah,9h
    lea     dx,draw_1
    int     21h

    add     posY,1; 
    call        SETPOS
    mov     ah,9h
    lea     dx,draw_2
    int     21h

    add     posY,1; 
    call        SETPOS
    mov     ah,9h
    lea     dx,draw_3
    int     21h

    sub     posY,3; 
RET

PRESS_KEY:
; настройка окна (режим 80х25)
    call        CLEAR
    call        DRAW

; --- установка курсору в рядок 1, стовпець 19
    MOV     AH, 2
    MOV     BH, 0
    MOV     DH, 1
    MOV     DL, 19
    INT     10H
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Изменить цвет фона Assembler](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1279014/%d0%98%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%86%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%84%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0-assembler)

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.